# I need help with Question 13, this is regarding the Loan Amortization Formula

Tags: calculus, finance

[image: Question 13 Source]
I have been working on 13, it is especially frustrating since I am so close to being done, but if there is anyone who could explain how to derive this, it would mean so much! I have retraced my work using Questions 4-6 and 11-12, but still no luck on getting the variable substitutions to work right!

Comment: Do you know the equation $$B\cdot (1+i)^N=m\cdot \frac{(1+i)^N-1}{i}?$$

Comment: I had not been familiar with seeing this formula! However, when I tried simplifying I still could not get the simplification to work right.
I multiplied by the denominator "i" to get iB but I fail to see how it could simplify to the needed formula in terms of m

Comment: I´ve posted an explanation. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have this equation:

$$B\cdot (1+i)^N=m\cdot \frac{(1+i)^N-1}{i} \qquad (*)$$

Explanation: Assume you borrow $B$ monetary units with an interest rate of $i\cdot 100$ percent per month. Then after N month the loan ($B$) has an value of $B\cdot (1+i)^N$. This is the future value of $B$. On the right hand side you have N monthly repayments of the loan. Every payment has a an amount of $m$. Every payment which is made at month $t$ is compounded so that it represents the future value as well. So you have an geometric series on the right hand side. Let $q=1+i$ then the right hand side is

$$m\cdot \sum_{x=0}^{N-1}q^x=m\cdot \left(q^0+q^1+q^2+\ldots +q^{N-1} \right)$$

The closed term for a partial sum of a geometric series is
$$\sum_{x=0}^{N-1} q^x= \frac{q^N-1}{q-1}$$

This is what you have with the definition of q: $\frac{(1+i)^N-1}{(1+i)-1}=\frac{(1+i)^N-1}{i}$

Hopefully the equation $(*)$ ist clear now. Now we can start to solve the equation for $m$. Multiplying both sides by $i$.

$$B\cdot (1+i)^N\cdot i=m\cdot \left((1+i)^N-1\right) $$

Dividing the equation by $\left((1+i)^N-1\right)$

$$B\cdot \frac{(1+i)^N\cdot i}{(1+i)^N-1}=m $$

Next we expand the fraction on the right by $(1+i)^{-N}$. Every summand has to be multiplied by that factor. Here the exponent rules are helpful. For instance, $a^b\cdot a^{-b}=a^{b-b}=a^0=1$

$$B\cdot \frac{(1+i)^N\cdot (1+i)^{-N}\cdot i}{\underbrace{(1+i)^N\cdot (1+i)^{-N}}_{=1}-1\cdot (1+i)^{-N}}=m $$

$$\boxed{B\cdot \frac{ i}{1- (1+i)^{-N}}=m} $$

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation, it helped so much! At this point in the semester, my brain has minimal functionality left, so thank you for helping me cross the finish line with this problem; it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @raf8302000 I´m glad that the answer helped. You´re welcome.